# FreeCodeCamp Chucky Monkey

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem: Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a two-dimensional array.

Why doesn't this work instead? `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=size)`

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    // Break it up
    // It's already broken :(
    arr = arr.slice();
    var arr2 = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i+=size) 
    {
      arr2.push(arr.slice(0, size));
      arr = arr.slice(size);
    }
    return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because every time for loop runs, the size of array is changed, and you are using the changed array length again in your loop.

So you keep a **variable pointer to the length of array outside the loop** so that you dont loose track of original array length